# Dimension of linear subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E = \mathbb R^n$. Let $\mathcal V$ be a linear subset of $E$ such that $$\forall X = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} \ne 0 \in \mathcal V, \forall i \in [\![ 1, n]\!], x_i \ne 0.$$ What is the dimension of $\mathcal V$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathcal V$ are linearly independent, what is the first coordinate of $y_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-x_1(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$?